# Remove specific item from React Native Navigator stack

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the app I am building I need to control the length of the route stack somehow, for an edge case scenario: a user can navigate from a posts-list to a post-detail, but some posts contain links to other post as well, so it could also be they are navigating from post to post for an unknown amount of times. In this case it could happen that the Navigators' stack becomes exceedingly large.

I would like to prevent this, but can't find any useful methods in the API docs. I already have some code in place that keeps track of the navigator, but I don't know if it's possible to remove a single item from the stack once the stack becomes too large:

```
manageRoutes() {
    let routeCache = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
    // Using 2 for test purposes
    if (routeCache.length > 2) {
        // Remove the item after the dashboard (default route)
        routeCache.splice(1,1);
        // The next line is not working as I hoped, it gives me 
        // a blank screen but no errors
        this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack(routeCache);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: what about `.replace` and `.replaceAtIndex`? You can keep your own short stack, instead of adding new scenes every time.

Comment: sorry, I am fairly new to RN and this is not ringing any bells... How would I 'keep my own short stack'?